# What could cause the file command in Linux to report a text file as binary data?

Tags: linux, bash, character-encoding

I have a couple of C++ source files (one .cpp and one .h) that are being reported as type **data** by the `file` command in Linux. When I run the `file -bi` command against these files, I'm given this output (same output for each file):

```
application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

Each file is clearly plain-text (I can view them in `vi`). What's causing `file` to misreport the type of these files? Could it be some sort of Unicode thing? Both of these files were created in Windows-land (using Visual Studio 2005), but they're being compiled in Linux (it's a cross-platform application).

Any ideas would be appreciated.

**Update**: I don't see any null characters in either file. I found some extended characters in the .cpp file (in a comment block), removed them, but `file` still reports the same encoding. I've tried forcing the encoding in SlickEdit, but that didn't seem to have an effect. When I open the file in `vim`, I see a `[converted]` line as soon as I open the file. Perhaps I can get vim to force the encoding?

Comment: Any null characters in them?

Comment: What's an easy way to test for nulls within the file? To my knowledge, they don't have any, but that's not to say that one snuck in somewhere...

Comment: Hmm... you could open them up in [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) and check for a `NUL` box (or search for `\0` with backslash transformations).

Comment: Try 'cat -v' to make control characters visible.

Comment: What happens when you run `file -e soft filename`?

Comment: @DanielBeck I get `{filename}: data` as the result.

Comment: What's the content of `/etc/magic` and `/etc/magic.mime`? Those are the tests excluded when using `-e soft`. What's in `/usr/share/misc/magic/`?

Comment: I don't have either an `/etc/magic` or an `/etc/magic.mime` file. The `/usr/share/misc/magic` file is 1/2 MB in size, so I'm not sure it's worth posting here.

Comment: Interesting. It's probably one of its rules that match. If you want a more specific answer, you really should post that file. You can probably post it to a paste site and link from here. Let me know when you do please.

Comment: Alternatively it's probably a Linux distribution's magic file out of the box, and we can take a look ourselves if you tell us what distribution.

Comment: It's a RHEL 6 platform, but I solved my problem last night. I posted an answer below detailing what I did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the issue using binary search to locate the problematic lines.

```
head -n {1/2 line count} file.cpp > a.txt
tail -n {1/2 line count} file.cpp > b.txt
```

Running `file` against each half, and repeating the process, helped me locate the offending line. I found a <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (`^P`) character embedded in it. Removing it solved the problem. I'll write myself a Perl script to search for these characters (and other extended) in the future.

A big thanks to everyone who provided an answer for all the tips!

Answer (score 7):

Vim tries very hard to make sense of whatever you throw at it without complaining. This makes it a relatively poor tool to use to diagnose `file`'s output.

Vim's "[converted]" notice indicates there was something in the file that vim wouldn't expect to see in the text encoding suggested by your locale settings (LANG etc).

Others have already suggested

- `cat -v`
- `xxd`

You could try grepping for non-ASCII characters.

- `grep -P '[\x7f-\xff]' filename`

The other possibility is non-standard line-endings for the platform (i.e. CRLF or CR) but I'd expect `file` to cope with that and report "DOS text file" or similar.

Comment: `file` doesn't [do a good job](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=980941) of detecting DOS text files either

Answer (score 5):

If you run `file -D filename`, `file` displays debugging information, including the tests it performs. Near the end, it will show what test was successful in determining the file type.

For a regular text file, it looks like this:

```
[31> 0 regex,=^package[ \t]+[0-9A-Za-z_:]+ *;,""]
1 == 0 = 0
ascmagic 1
filename.txt: ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators
```

This will tell you what it found to determine it's that mime type.

Comment: I don't see a -D option in my file install (v5.04)...

Comment: Try -d instead. That works with file-5.03 as installed on Fedora 11.

Comment: Notifying @JonahBishop about garyjohn's comment. My post was written for the `file` included with OS X. My Debian 6 has neither `-d` nor `-D` though...

Comment: The -d flag works for me, but there's so much output I'm not sure what to look for...

Answer (score 1):

I was working with pretty large files so solutions like `cat -v`, which simply print everything *including* non-printable characters, wasn't an option.

To find *only* lines that contain non-printable characters, I used:

```
grep -n '[^[:print:]]' Exploit.in_noctrls.txt
```

Comment: ...or if your `grep` doesn't know that syntax, the Perl equivalent: `perl -ne 'print if /[^[:print:]\s]/;' file`

Answer (score 0):

It *could* be that the files have been saved with a BOM at the beginning of them, although I would have thought a recent-ish version of the file binary should recognise that too.

Have you tried dumping them through something like "head -2  | xxd" and seeing if there's a BOM present?

*BOM = Byte Order Mark - sometimes present in unicode text files.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: That an interesting tip. I've run both files through xxd, and I see no BOM in the first character position. Each file starts out with a giant comment block, so I see a bunch of slashes to start.

Comment: Care to share an excerpt?

Comment: This is what I see from the xxd dump: `0000000: 2f2f 2f2f 2f2f 2f2f 2f2f 2f2f 2f2f 2f2f  ////////////////`

Answer (score 0):

It probably is a non-ASCII character from Unicode or some other character set. Since you're using `vi`, which in most Linux distributions is some version of `vim`, you can search for that character by typing

```
/[<Ctrl-V>x80-<Ctrl-V>xff]
```

and hitting Enter, where `<Ctrl-V>` means typing `v` while pressing the `Ctrl` key. Similarly, you can search for nulls (as Mehrdad suggested) with this:

```
/<Ctrl-V>x00
```

Comment: This search resulted in a comment block containing some extended characters in my .cpp file. However, I don't see any similar characters in the .h...

Comment: I updated my answer to include searching for nulls as Mehrdad suggested.

Comment: I don't see any null characters in either file. :(

Answer (score 0):

Which charset/encoding/(codepage) are the files in?
Perhaps the files have stray character(s). typically from bad cross-encoding between different platforms.  Invalid data in you files may be causing `file` to report as you have described.   You can test the validity of a file for a particular charset encoding by testing it with `recode`  (or `iconv`).

Follow the link for  a list of *[Common character encodings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding#Common_character_encodings)*

This script lists charset encodings (from `$my_csets`) which aren't valid for your file(s).  You can list all charsets via: `recode -l`

```
file="$1"    
my_csets="UTF-16 UTF-8 windows-1250 ASCII"

# Use the next lines to test all charsets
# =======================================
# all_csets=$(recode -l |sed -ne "/^[^:/]/p" | awk '{print $1}')
# my_csets=$all_csets

for cset in $my_csets ;do 
  <"$1" recode $cset.. &>/dev/null || echo  "$cset  ERROR: $?"
done
```